# Two consecutive animations synchronised with one longer animation

Tags: python, manim

In particular, I would like to smoothly zoom out and then zoom in all the while an object rotates. I cannot seem to control runtimes separately and I couldn't figure out how to use LaggedStart or Succession to achieve this. I also couldn't make an updater work – the width does not change at all. I'm including the last try on the updater.

```
class Rectangles(MovingCameraScene):
 def construct(self):
     rect1 = Rectangle(height=4.2, width=9.3)
     staticobj = Rectangle(height=8,width=2,fill_color=BLUE).shift(RIGHT*7)
     self.add(rect1,staticobj)
     self.camera.frame.set(width=20)
     x = ValueTracker(-.99)
     def zoom_level(inp):
         inp.set(width=math.exp(10 / (x.get_value() ** 2 - 1) + 20))

     self.camera.frame.add_updater(zoom_level)
     self.play(Rotate(rect1, angle=PI / 2, about_point=ORIGIN),x.animate.set_value(0.99),run_time=5)
     self.wait(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever stumbles upon this: the solution I came up with in the end was to use UpdateFromAlphaFunc.

```
class Rectangles(MovingCameraScene):
  def construct(self):
   rect1 = Rectangle(height=4.2, width=9.3)
   staticobj = Rectangle(height=8,width=2,fill_color=BLUE).shift(RIGHT*7)
   self.add(rect1,staticobj)
   self.camera.frame.set(width=20)
    def zoom_level(inp,alpha):
     inp.set(width=20+5-20*(alpha-0.5)**2)

   self.play(Rotate(rect1, angle=PI / 2, about_point=ORIGIN),
             UpdateFromAlphaFunc(self.camera.frame,zoom_level),run_time=5)
   self.wait(1)
```